# XPath with "following/preceding-sibling::" executes differently (fails) in .NET for second node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have an XPath expression that returns nodes whose indexes are dependent upon/relative to their neighboring nodes.  It works great in online tests (I tried it with two sites: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and http://www.xpathtester.com), but in my test app in .NET it only works... well, partially.

Sample XML:

```
<Root>
    <IN1>
        <IN1_2>
            <IN1_2_1>100</IN1_2_1>
        </IN1_2>
    </IN1>
    <IN2>
        <IN2_2>100.1</IN2_2>
    </IN2>
    <IN1>
        <IN1_2>
            <IN1_2_1>200</IN1_2_1>
        </IN1_2>
    </IN1>
    <IN2>
        <IN2_2>200.1</IN2_2>
    </IN2>
    <IN2>
        <IN2_2>200.2</IN2_2>
    </IN2>
</Root>
```

The XPath queries:

1. `//IN1[2]/following-sibling::IN2[count(preceding-sibling::IN1)=2][1]//IN2_2`
2. `//IN1[2]/following-sibling::IN2[count(preceding-sibling::IN1)=2][2]//IN2_2`

The idea is to be able to index the IN2 nodes relative to the specified preceding IN1 node, i.e. for the first IN1 node the following IN2[1] would return the 100.1 child, and for the second IN1 node the following IN2[1] (i.e. same index as above) would return the 200.1 child.  (And of course IN2[2] would return the 200.2 child, etc.)

So the first XPath works everywhere as expected and returns `<IN2_2>200.1</IN2_2>`.
The second returns `<IN2_2>200.2</IN2_2>`, also as expected, *but only in the online tests*; it returns nothing in my test app!! (`XmlDocument.SelectNodes` returns an empty list)

The test app is an utterly simple WinForms app written in VS 2013 referencing .NET 4.5.  The code basically creates the `XmlDocument` with the specified XML and calls `SelectNodes` with the above XPath.

I made absolutely sure it is the very same XML and XPath in both scenarios -- I stopped at a breakpoint on the `SelectNodes` call, and copy-pasted the `XmlDocument.InnerXml` value and the string I'm passing to it directly from the debugger into the aforementioned online "XPath tester" sites.

Just purely as a sanity check, I tried this XPath: `//IN2[3]//IN2_2` and it worked fine (returned that elusive node with 200.2 value) in my test app.

I don't have any special XML-related packages or anything else "unusual" installed that would mess with this.  (Besides, the first one, with index [1], works fine!)

Running out of options...  Not sure how else to get this done (maybe there is another XPath I could use, but I can't figure it out.)  They should both work.  Is this maybe some weird known issue (bug?) with .NET?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if whoever -1'd it would explain why?  It is a real issue, where XML/XPath engines exhibit different behavior, and it actually got me stuck!  If the question was inappropriate, I'd like to know why so that I can avoid repeating that mistake (if there was one) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I got it!!

I guess asking (my first) question on SO gave me an extra boost :-), and I really went to town on that XPath, trying things I haven't before.

Here's the version that seems to be working everywhere:

`(//IN1[2]/following-sibling::IN2[count(preceding-sibling::IN1)=2])[2]//IN2_2`

(here's the original, for easier reference):

`//IN1[2]/following-sibling::IN2[count(preceding-sibling::IN1)=2][2]//IN2_2`

I've no idea why it worked without the "extra" grouping/the parentheses in the online test sites -- or conversely, why it *didn't* work in .NET *without* those parentheses...

Unfortunately I don't know enough about XML to decide which is the correct/better XPath syntax.  I only know that this last one works in both scenarios!

Hopefully this might help someone facing the same issue.